# Start date of archived task via API Rest bonita

Tags: rest, api, business-process-management, bonita

I am trying to get the start date of an archived task via the API Rest of Bonita BPM portal (7.1.3 version) but I don't find the proper method.

For example, I am using:

```
.../bonita/API/bpm/archivedTask?p=0&f=processId=processIdNumber
```

and the only dates that I get are:

```
[
    {
        ...
        "assigned_date": "2016-10-13 12:22:50.456",
        ...
        "reached_state_date": "2016-10-13 12:22:51.717",
        ...
        "archivedDate": "2016-10-13 12:22:51.729",
        ...
        "dueDate": "2016-10-13 13:21:31.266",
        "last_update_date": "2016-10-13 12:22:51.717"
    }
]
```

Neither of these dates is the start date.

Any idea?

Thanks a lot.
Best regards.

Answer (score 1):

Actually the `archivedTask` API only return the latest state of the archived task. A human task go through 3 states: `initializing`, `ready` and `completed`.  `archivedTask` API only return information about the `completed` state.

What you want is probably the `reached_state_date` of the `ready` state.

Solution is to use the `archivedFlowNode` API that will return an array with one entry per state.

Here is an example to filter for a specific case id (i.e. running process instance, e.g. 123), a specific task name (e.g. Step1) and to get only `ready` state information (you can limit `c` value to 1 instead of 10 as you probably only expect one result):

```
/API/bpm/archivedFlowNode?p=0&c=10&f=caseId%3d123&f=state%3dready&f=name%3dStep1
```

Note that `%3d` is the `=` sign URL encoded.

Also note that `caseId` is the id of the running case. If you only have the id of the archived case, you can get it by calling the following API:

```
/API/bpm/archivedCase/456
```

where 456 is the archived case id. On the response case id is stored in `sourceObjectId` attribute.